# How to test whether a function called from within a tkinter GUI yields a RunTimeWarning?

Tags: python

I know little about Python warnings and exceptions but find myself in a situation where I'm designing a tkinter gui that has an option to execute an outside function imported from a module written by someone else. The function performs calculations but produces no graphs.

Numeric stability issues may arise when I call the function, in which case it returns an output along with a RunTimeWarning that indicates the output may not be very reliable and suggests I adjust the input I used when calling the function.

Of course, the warnings are not visible to the user from within the gui, so I'd like to inform the user of the warning and give them options to proceed. The pseudo code would look something like the following:

output=outside_function(input)

if outside_function issued RuntimeWarning:
do something such as issuing error message, asking user to adjust input,etc.

else:
proceed with further calculations utilizing the output obtained.

I apologize that this question is somewhat vague and lacks a minimal reproducible example. However is there some way, perhaps using the warnings module, which allows me to determine whether
**outside_function issued RuntimeWarning** is true or false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the warning extended `Warning` (which `RuntimeWarning` should), you should be able to catch it with the `catch_warnings` context manager, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#testing-warnings) for an example.

But you should be able to do something like:

```
import warnings
with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
    outside_function(...)
    # code to check if there was a warning
    if len(w) > 0: 
        # do something, e.g. check to see the warning type/whatnot
```

Comment: So I tried what you've suggested, using an example I ran outside the GUI that doesn't raise any warnings. The output indicated w had one entry, and w was given by

```[<warnings.WarningMessage object at 0x7fbd3927b070>]```

On the other hand, if I used an input which is known to raise RunTimeWarnings, I again saw w (not the same as above), which had one element. However, the warning did not appear on the screen.

Comment: What does the warning message say? Yeah, it catches the warning, so you would probably need to emit the warning again if you wanted it to show up.

Comment: ```Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/Users/fishbacp/artifact_repair.py", line 12
    ica.fit(raw_filt,picks=None,decim=1)
RuntimeWarning: Using n_components=0.999999 (resulting in n_components_=6) may lead to an unstable mixing matrix estimation because the ratio between the largest (46) and smallest (2.2e-05) variances is too large (> 1e6); consider setting n_components=0.999999 or an integer <= 5 ```

Comment: Followed by:

```Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/Users/fishbacp/artifact_repair.py", line 12
    ica.fit(raw_filt,picks=None,decim=1)
RuntimeWarning: Using n_components=0.999999 (resulting in n_components_=6) may lead to an unstable mixing matrix estimation because the ratio between the largest (46) and smallest (2.2e-05) variances is too large (> 1e6); consider setting n_components=0.999999 or an integer <= 5```

Comment: Those look like the same warnings?

Comment: Yes, for clarity, the function is applied to a multivariate signal, ```raw```, of size num_times by num_channels, where num_channels is the number of channels. The errors above, which arise from ```ica.fit``` indicate it arose for two of my channels. (The above are for warnings before I added your code.)

Comment: What is the question? The warnings could've been the same warning, but different instances of (objects representing) the same warning.

Comment: Apologies for confusion I've caused. It appears that a small code discrepancy is what produced results that were inconsistent with one another. Correcting that, I now see that for all cases when my previous work yielded RunTimeWarnings, your additional code indicates len(w)>0. Likewise, when no warnings result, len(w)=0. This is precisely what I wanted.Thanks so very much.